# Selecting gives one row, updating affects 2

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, upsert

When I select using WHERE clause that uses the same columns as a UNIQUE constraint "mytable_uniq_detail_date" (detail_id and date), I get a single row, but when I upsert a row data that (as I think) would update this row only, I get two rows affected:

```
mysql> describe mytable;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| detail_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pruefer     | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Pruefmittel | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| next_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bemerkung   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable WHERE detail_id=3 and date='2020-07-03';
+-----+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id  | detail_id | pruefer       | Pruefmittel             | date       | next_date  | bemerkung |
+-----+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 116 |         3 | Max Mustemann | Ein Werkzeug | 2020-07-03 | 2021-07-03 | keine     |
+-----+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mutable (detail_id, pruefer, Pruefmittel, date, next_date, bemerkung)
    -> VALUES ('3', 'Max Mustermann','Anderer Werkzeug','2020-07-03','2021-07-03', 'keine')
    -> ;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3-2020-07-03' for key 'mytable_uniq_detail_date'

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (detail_id, pruefer, Pruefmittel, date, next_date, bemerkung)  
VALUES ('3', 'Max Mustermann','Anderer Werkzeug','2020-07-03','2021-07-03', 'keine1')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  pruefer = 'Max Mustermann', Pruefmittel = 'Anderer Werkzeug', next_date = '2021-07-03', bemerkung = 'keine1';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

The constraint was added like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_uniq_detail_date
UNIQUE (detail_id, date);
```

How can this be? What am I missing and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

From [MySQL docs, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, **2 if an existing row is updated**, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

You don't have to fix anything. The existing row was updated, affected-rows returned 2.

As to *why* the MySQL developers decided it should do that, I guess they wanted to differentiate to show whether the statement did an insert of a new row (return 1), or an update of an existing one where the `DUPLICATE` kicked in (return 2), or a non-update when the `DUPLICATE` kicked in but the update was moot (return 0).